# NodeJS API: having trouble passing 2 parameters to request response

Tags: node.js, api, httprequest, httpresponse

I am having trouble passing 2 ids via request response function. I can pass 1 id/argument without any issue but having trouble passing 2 arguments below is a snippet of my code:

server:

```
var http = require("http");
var org = require("../controllers/org");
var school = require("../controllers/school");
var academicSession = require("../controllers/academicSession");
var term = require("../controllers/term");
var gradingperiod = require("../controllers/gradingperiod");
var course = require("../controllers/course");
var stu = require("../controllers/student");
var cls = require("../controllers/class");
var user = require("../controllers/user");
var demo = require("../controllers/demographic");
var enroll = require("../controllers/enrollment");
var teach = require("../controllers/teacher");
var crscls = require("../controllers/schoolcs");
var enr = require("../controllers/enrollqrys");
var settings = require("../settings");
var httpMsgs = require("../core/httpMsgs");


http.createServer(function (req, resp) {
    switch (req.method) {
        case "GET":

            if (req.url === "/") {
                httpMsgs.showHome(req, resp);
            }
            else if (req.url === "/orgs") {
                org.getOrgs(req, resp);
            }
            else if (req.url.match("/orgs/[0-9]+$")) {
                var idorg = "[0-9]+";
                var patt = new RegExp("/orgs/" + idorg);
                if (patt.test(req.url)) {
                    patt = new RegExp(idorg);
                    var id = patt.exec(req.url);
                    org.getOrg(req, resp, id);
                }
                else {
                    httpMsgs.show404(req, resp);
                }
            }

            ***else if (req.url.match("/schools/[0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+/classes/[0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+/enrollments$")) {
                var idcl = "[0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+";
                var idsc = "[0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+";
                var str = idcl + "[0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+" + idsc;
                var patt = new RegExp("/schools/" + idcl + "/classes/" + idsc + "/enrollments");
                if (patt.test(req.url)) {
                    patt = new RegExp(str);
                    var id = patt.exec(req.url);
                    enr.getEnrollmentsForClassInSchools(req, resp, id, arg2);
                }
                else {
                    httpMsgs.show404(req, resp);
                }
            }***
```

enrollqrys.js:

```
var db = require("../core/db");
var httpMsgs = require("../core/httpMsgs");


exports.getEnrollmentsForClassInSchools = function (req, resp, id, arg2) {
    db.executeSql("EXEC dbo.getEnrollmentsForClassInSchools @clid = '" + id + "'" + ", @scid = '" + arg2 + "'", function (data, err) {
        if (err) {

            httpMsgs.show500(req, resp, err);
        }
        else {
            //resp.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });
            //resp.write(JSON.stringify(data));
            //resp.end();
            httpMsgs.sendJson(req, resp, data);
        }


    });

};

exports.getStudentsForClassInSchool = function (req, resp, id, id) {
    db.executeSql("EXEC dbo.getEnrollmentsForClassInSchools @clid = '" + clid + "'" + ", @scid =" + scid, function (data, err) {
        if (err) {

            httpMsgs.show500(req, resp, err);
        }
        else {
            //resp.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });
            //resp.write(JSON.stringify(data));
            //resp.end();
            httpMsgs.sendJson(req, resp, data);
        }


    });

};
```

I get a not referenced error when testing this GET. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will add that I am new to both javascript and nodejs

Error below:

Started listening at: 9000
C:\Users\THOMMA02\source\repos\NodejsConsoleApp1\NodejsConsoleApp1\core\server.js:281
                    enr.getEnrollmentsForClassInSchools(req, resp, id, arg2);
                                                                       ^

ReferenceError: arg2 is not defined
    at Server. (C:\Users\THOMMA02\source\repos\NodejsConsoleApp1\NodejsConsoleApp1\core\server.js:281:72)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:619:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:112:17)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...

Comment: where does the error show ? what is not referenced ?

Comment: Error has been added

Comment: yeah so on `enr.getEnrollmentsForClassInSchools(req, resp, id, arg2);` I see you defined id but I don't see arg2.

Comment: ahhh shoot, I see it. I think i can fix that. thanks

Comment: also please keep in mind your getStudentsForClassInSchool is also wrong, you used two id in function definition but inside function you refer to them as clid and scid.

Comment: awesome thanks for pointing that out as well.